# Drop down list lookup field SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

I would like to create a list with inventory on it. This would be just numbers like A1 through A24 (List A). Is there a way to create a lookup field in another list (B) with a column that shows those numbers? Click the drop-down arrow and see the numbers displayed form List A? I know there are only certain types of columns that are supported in Lookup Fields. What type of list should List A be? A custom list? I can't seem to get List B to show any info from List A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use custom list for your purpose.

Steps:

- Create List A as a custom list. Add your data (A1 to A24) in list.
- Create List B and create new lookup column, set the name of the column.
- Choose "List A" in **Get information from** dropdown list. Choose the column name which is in List A in **In this column** dropdown list.

Now you can see the values of List A in List B's column.

Further, you can check the limitations of lookup field in this [link](http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.in/2012/01/sharepoint-not-all-column-types-can-be.html).